# How to replace two consecutive special characters in string using regex?

Tags: javascript, regex, web, replace, character

I need to replace the `"[` by `[` and `]"` by `]` combinations everytime found in this string.

I tried this but it doesn't work

```
var myString = myString .replace(/]"/i, /]/);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- need to use single quotes on the outside so that myString is actually
  a single string
- need a backslash before ] in regex
- do the second argument of replace as a string, not a regex probably
  also should use the g flag for global
- so `myVar = myVar.replace( /\]"/g, "]").replace( /"\[/g, "[")`

Answer (score 1):

I can assume that you want to convert/format some kind of string to an object, You might take advantage of `JSON.parse()` function. [See documentation here](https://www.google.dz/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0ahUKEwjLodH0tdHUAhVJXRQKHWrWDUYQFggmMAA&url=https%3A%2F%2Fdeveloper.mozilla.org%2Fen%2Fdocs%2FWeb%2FJavaScript%2FReference%2FGlobal_Objects%2FJSON%2Fparse&usg=AFQjCNHkowMNeO8CgweprUJz3xDY9HxuPQ)